# How often group of queried nodes are changed in snowball/avalanche consensus algorithm?

Tags: avalanche

I think I understand snowball consensus algorithm with exception of 1 think.

Node polls 5-10 random nodes N times and choose color. Is it querying always same list of nodes? Or it is changed after some iteration? Or everytime it queries it chooses a new set of nodes?